# Storing a UIView in Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, parse-platform

I'm trying to capture a signature on a UIView and store it in parse.com. Is there a simple way to do this? I took a look at parse's options for storing data but couldn't find an option that would fit.

[image]

Comment: What does the signature look like? i think you need to save the data for the signature. And then load it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView *myview = [UIView new];

....

PFObject *viewObj = [PFObject OObjectWith......

viewObj[@"myview"] = myview; 

...

[viewObj save...];
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `Parse` but it sounds like what you want to save is an image (like a JPEG or PNG file), so you might want to upload it to a file server and store the relataive or absolute path in `Parse` as a `String`